# 8 Puzzle in Java Using Bredth-First Search

Tags: java

Ok so I understand the Bredth First Search Iterates nodes and goes to the next one that is the largest. I also have no idea how exactly that relates to the 8 Puzzle Game. Here is my code:

```
public static void breadthFirstSearch(int[] num, int m, Vector solution) {
    Queue t = new PriorityQueue();
    ArrayList Visited = new ArrayList();
    blankNode = 0;
    int temp;
    printArray(num);
    for (int i : num) {
        if (num[i] == m) {
            blankNode = i;
            System.out.println(blankNode);
        }
    }


    System.out.println(blankNode);
    printArray(num);

}

private static void printArray(int[] num) {
    for (int i : num) {
        System.out.print(num[i] + ",");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

private static int[] moveUp(int[] num, int blankSpace) {
    int temp = 0;
    if (blankSpace != 6 && blankSpace != 1 && blankSpace != 2) {
        blankNode = blankSpace - 3;
        temp = num[blankSpace - 3];
        num[blankSpace - 3] = num[blankSpace];
        num[blankSpace] = temp;
    }

    return num;
}

private static int[] moveLeft(int[] num, int blankSpace) {
    int temp;
    if (blankSpace != 0 && blankSpace != 3 && blankSpace != 6) {
        blankNode = blankSpace - 1;
        temp = num[blankSpace - 1];
        num[blankSpace - 1] = num[blankSpace];
        num[blankSpace] = temp;
    }
    return num;
}

private static int[] moveDown(int[] num, int blankSpace) {
    int temp;
    if (blankSpace != 6 && blankSpace != 7 && blankSpace != 8) {
        blankNode = blankSpace + 3;
        temp = num[blankSpace + 3];
        num[blankSpace + 3] = num[blankSpace];
        num[blankSpace] = temp;
    }
    return num;
}

private static int[] moveRight(int[] num, int blankSpace) {
    int temp;
    if (blankSpace != 2 && blankSpace != 5 && blankSpace != 8) {
        blankNode = blankSpace + 1;
        temp = num[blankSpace + 1];
        num[blankSpace + 1] = num[blankSpace];
        num[blankSpace] = temp;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Now, in the method breadthFirstSearch I need to play tiles with the num array. So imagine the num array as

```
045
789
312
```

and the blank node is 7, I need to get it down to the bottom right corner by only swapping it with numbers above below to the right or left of it. m gives me the number that is blank. How can breath first search be used here to do this? Do I just need to check every possible combination and choose the correct one? Please help.

Comment: So we should do your homework?

Comment: If you feel you have to link the description and code on dropbox instead of directly posting it here I have the feeling it's way too much for SO and thus out of scope. What did you try so far? Where did you fail?

Comment: @StimpsonCat by no means, all I'm asking for is an explanation,  not doing it for me.

Comment: @Arseniy the stackoverflow does not work this way. You have to ask a very specific problem, issue, bug etc. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to understand why posts like this get downvotes.

Comment: Ok I am taking this post down sorry for your time